# Communication between winform client and server's web service

Tags: .net, web-services, client, communication

currently I'm an internee and about to join in a project in which I have to take responsible for implementing the server side part.

The scenario:
_There are many kiosks, each runs a winform application, this application read barcode from customer's card and then send the info to server.
_The server has several web services, each service can process the info received from client and send back the result. The server also has the ability to display logs/reports for the administrator to see.

So how can I implement the communication between the client and server? I have researched a bit and see two solutions: .Net socket and WCF but don't know which one is better for this situation or is there any other better way? And the report display ability I can implement it just as a normal web application right?

Also, I would love to receive links to tutorials similar to my problem.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks a lot!